# My code is Running in eclipse but not working in github action why?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, github-actions, maven-surefire-plugin

```
name: Java CI with Maven

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: Set up JDK 21.0.2
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 21.0.2

 
      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn -B clean package --file pom.xml
```

Update maven.yml · vjamdade1/19thFeb@648e4a4

When I run the build with clean package in my eclipse it work perfectly but When it is in Github actions it is not run correctly.Can anyone give me the solution for that?

Comment: Could you add more context to your question? What is the error? What is your project configuration? Did you try updating the actions you are using in your workflow to use the latest versions available?

Comment: THis issue is resolved due to headless I am facing issue. I have added in my code screen resolution only..